# Is there any simple way to run same SQL script on multiple remote SQL Server databases at once?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Our company has many branches, each of them located in a different country.

So when I update the database in any country over the VPN connection then I need to update the same database in another country one by one over the vpn connection.

It is very tiresome job....

So I was think that there could be any easy trick to update multiple databases in different countries easily. So I am developing a stored procedure which will connect to each database one after one over the vpn and read the script from a `.sql` file and execute the script in the remote database over vpn.

So please have look at my script and tell me how to do it.

Here is a table structure where I will put all my remote db details.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DBDetails]
(
[ServerName] [varchar](max)     NULL,
[DBName] [varchar](max)         NULL,
[UserID] [varchar](max)         NULL,
[Password] [varchar](max)       NULL,
[CountryCode] [varchar](2)      NULL
) 

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE DB CURSOR FOR SELECT ServerName,DBName,UserID,Password,CountryCode FROM    DBDetails 
OPEN DB
DECLARE @ServerName     varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @DBName         varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @UserID         varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @Password       varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @CountryCode    varchar(2)

FETCH NEXT FROM DB INTO @ServerName,@DBName,@UserID,@Password,@CountryCode
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

-- here I need some help for opening db connection and read sql file and execute  the statement
-- Please help here 

FETCH NEXT FROM DB INTO @ServerName,@DBName,@UserID,@Password,@CountryCode
 END
 CLOSE DB
 DEALLOCATE DB
```

thanks

Comment: Check out [Red-Gate SQL MultiScript](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/) - it does exactly this

Comment: basically i don't want to use any 3rd part use...rather need to develop our own.